# Why doesn't matplotlib widget blitting work with wxpython?

Tags: matplotlib, wxpython

The following code example uses the RectangleSelector widget, so that we should see a continuously updated rectangular patch over the plot. However, nothing can be seen, unless we set `useblit=False`. What's wrong?

This is with matplotlib 2.2.2 and wxpython 4.0.1 on linux. The tkagg backend works fine.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import matplotlib
from matplotlib.widgets import RectangleSelector

if __name__ == '__main__':
    matplotlib.use('wxagg')
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    figure = plt.figure()
    rect = RectangleSelector(figure.gca(), (lambda e1, e2: print(e1, e2)), useblit=True)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: In WIN7 it works perfect with both backends and useblit settings

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using Linux. Check following link:
https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/11425
Wayland seems to have a bug when blitting.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).